# document.defaultView === window circular reference?

Tags: javascript, dom

So I read that `document.defaultView` in JavaScript DOM points to the `window` object. Doesn't this become a circular reference and crash the document?

Since I'm new to JavaScript, DOM, and Black Magic, it stumps me that things like this are valid:

```
console.log(window.document.defaultView === window); //true
console.log(window.document.defaultView.document.defaultView === window); //true
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's wrong with a circular reference? JavaScript (especially DOM) is full of them.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scimonster stated in a comment: circular references aren't invalid.

Comment: Ah! Another surprise discovery.